# IBPP Events implementation?

Tags: c++, events, firebird

What is the easiest method of implementing an EventInterface listener in c++?

My 'listener' scraps of code look like:

```
class EventInterface
{
public:
    virtual void ibppEventHandler(Events eventsSet, const std::string& eventName, int count) = 0;
    virtual ~EventInterface() { };
};
    ..
    someFunc(){
    IBPP::Database db2 = IBPP::DatabaseFactory("", DBName, Login, Pass);
     db2->Connect();
     IBPP::Events ev = IBPP::EventsFactory(db2);
    }
```

According to documentation here
[IBPP::Events](http://www.ibpp.org/reference/events) and here
[class EventInterface](http://www.ibpp.org/reference/eventinterface)

this should be nice and easy. What am I missing?

Comment: _"this should be nice and easy. What am I missing?"_ Elaborate in which ways this doesn't work for you actually. Your question is very vague.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @πάντα ῥεῖ, but honestly said, I'm out of ideas. 
The point is how to implement a listener function so it would be triggered by an event sent by firebird DB. For the moment being (as you can see) it is "implemented", but the function is never called on event. If you have a scrap of "working" code I would really appreciate it.